# PasswordToggleDrawable с разными цветами для каждого состояния

Tags: android, xml

Есть следующая проблема: когда пароль скрыт, у passwordToggle должен быть один цвет (серый), а когда открыт - другой (см. скриншот №3). Не могу понять, как это реализовать. Сейчас passwordToogleDrawable представляет из себя следующий селектор:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_password_visible" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_password_invisible"/>
```

Первый ресурс - глазок синего цвета, второй - серого. Тем не менее, значок остается серым в любом случае (см. первый и второй скриншот).
Вариант с passwordToggleTint не подходит, потому что изменяет цвет для двух состояний. Кто сталкивался с подобной задачей? Как решить этот вопрос? Видел реализацию, когда человек в passwordToggleTint пихал селектор, который находился в /res/color, но, ИМХО, этот вариант довольно таки костыльный. Кто сталкивался с подобным?

[image: Пароль скрыт]

[image: Пароль видимый]

[image: Дизайн]

Comment: Попробуйте таки сделать селектор по гайду: [color-list-resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) - ничего сложного там нет. Потому как похоже, что ваша картинка в любом случае закрашивается неким дефолтным "оттенком".

Comment: @woesss прямо сейчас написал тестовый биндинг адаптер для этого:
https://gist.github.com/sainote/714c1044c96d15e84e0b5f13166d5353
Цвет все равно один и тот же для всех состояний (красный). И это с условием, что я убрал селектор с картинками, т.е. это для дефолтной картинки. Может я с состояниями накосячил?

Comment: `state_enabled` - это вроде не то, скорее `state_checked`

Comment: @woesss точно, проглядел, спасибо, заработало. Допишу адаптер, кину как пример в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря комментариям назрело решение. (код ниже предназначен для MVVM, однако спокойно переносится на MVP и пр.)

// my_layout.xml

```
           <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    style="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearance"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/ic_password_visible"
                    (параметр для BindingAdapter'a)
                    app:customColorTint="@{viewmodel.passwordTintBackground}">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        style="@style/EditTextLayoutAppearance"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/password"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

// MyViewModelImpl.kt

```
override val passwordTintBackground: IntArray
    get() = intArrayOf(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.colorBlueDarker),
        ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.colorGreyDarker))
```

// MyDataBindingAdapters.kt

```
@BindingAdapter("app:customColorTint")
fun TextInputLayout.setCustomColorTint(colors: IntArray) {
    this.setPasswordVisibilityToggleTintList(ColorStateList(arrayOf(
        intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_checked),
        intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_checked)
    ), colors))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение автора вопроса несколько перемудрено, хотя он сам упомянул вариант попроще.

В папке `../res/` создаём папку `color/` и в ней файл, например `passwordTintList.xml`
Или через менюшки создаём такой ресурс: `правый клик->New->Android Resource File`. В диалоге: *Resource type: color*, *Root element: selector*.
С содержимым вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@color/colorBlueDarker" />

    <item android:color="@color/colorGreyDarker" />
</selector>
```

И прямо в разметке присваиваем этот ресурс атрибуту `passwordToggleTint`:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearance"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/ic_password_visible"
    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/passwordTintList">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        style="@style/EditTextLayoutAppearance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```